# How to enable LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE when looking up entities with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How can I achieve the equivalent of this code:

```
tx.begin();
Widget w = em.find(Widget.class, 1L, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
w.decrementBy(4);
em.flush();
tx.commit();
```

... but using Spring and Spring-Data-JPA annotations?

The basis of my existing code is:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class WidgetServiceImpl implements WidgetService
{
  /** The spring-data widget repository which extends CrudRepository<Widget, Long>. */
  @Autowired
  private WidgetRepository repo;

  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public void updateWidgetStock(Long id, int count)
  {
    Widget w = this.repo.findOne(id);
    w.decrementBy(4);
    this.repo.save(w);
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to specify that everything in the `updateWidgetStock` method should be done with a pessimistic lock set.

There is a Spring Data JPA annotation `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Lock` which allows you to set a `LockModeType`, but I don't know if it's valid to put it on the `updateWidgetStock` method.  It sounds more like an annotation on the `WidgetRepository`, because the Javadoc says:

> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository 
>   @Target(value=METHOD) 
>   @Retention(value=RUNTIME) 
>   @Documented 
>   public @interface Lock 
>   Annotation used to specify the LockModeType to be used when executing the query. It will be evaluated when using Query on a query method or if you derive the query from the method name.

... so that doesn't seem to be helpful.

How can I make my `updateWidgetStock()` method execute with `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` set?

Comment: Both answers to this question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`@Lock` is supported on CRUD methods as of version 1.6 of Spring Data JPA (in fact, there's already a [milestone](https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.6.0.M1/) available). See this [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-173) for more details.

With that version you simply declare the following:

```
interface WidgetRepository extends Repository<Widget, Long> {

  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  Widget findOne(Long id);
}
```

This will cause the CRUD implementation part of the backing repository proxy to apply the configured `LockModeType` to the `find(…)` call on the `EntityManager`.

Comment: This @Lock already works with spring-data-jpa 1.4.1 in my testing... but anyway question is, how can i pass the lock type?  I don't want to always use pessimistic lock, lots of senarios are mostly read.  But when i know i'm doing writes, and that there will be contention i'd like to use a pessimistic lock.  Can i create findOneLock(String, LockModeType)?

Comment: ah ok, is see in 1.4.1 it's working when i add it to an overridden findOne, but not when i add it do my own findByXxx.  The main question remains, how can i use a lock some of the time but not all of the time.

Comment: Small question in regards with this. Will the annotation be taken into account if I annotate a method "findOnePessimstic(...)" with a default implementation calling findOne(...) ? This would allow to keep optimistic locking behavior for findOne, and offer pessimistic locking without the need of @Query.

Comment: You should be aware that in the case you are trying to use spring-data-rest you are in trouble as spring data rest does read only transactions where doing "select for update" is illegal - and these call exactly findOne ...

Comment: At the moment @Lock is taken into account if it is placed on method name derived or query (not native). What if I need the same name derived method to be both pessimistic/no lock depending on the business logic? How to overcome it?

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to override standard `findOne()` method, you can acquire a lock in your custom method by using `select ... for update` query just like this:

```
/**
 * Repository for Wallet.
 */
public interface WalletRepository extends CrudRepository<Wallet, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Wallet> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("select w from Wallet w where w.id = :id")
    Wallet findOneForUpdate(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

However, if you are using PostgreSQL, things can get a little complicated when you want to set lock timeout to avoid deadlocks. PostgreSQL ignores standard property `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` set in JPA properties or in `@QueryHint` annotation.

The only way I could get it working was to create a custom repository and set timeout manually before locking an entity. It's not nice but at least it's working:

```
public class WalletRepositoryImpl implements WalletRepositoryCustom {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


@Override
public Wallet findOneForUpdate(Long id) {
    // explicitly set lock timeout (necessary in PostgreSQL)
    em.createNativeQuery("set local lock_timeout to '2s';").executeUpdate();

    Wallet wallet = em.find(Wallet.class, id);

    if (wallet != null) {
        em.lock(wallet, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    }

    return wallet;
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not refresh the `entityManager` cache. You must manually do an `entityManager.refresh(wallet)`

Comment: why would you want to have a timeout if lock ends at the end of transaction anyway?

Comment: could you please provide some supporting evidence for: PostgreSQL ignores standard property javax.persistence.lock.timeout set in JPA properties or in @QueryHint annotation.

I am using:
```
    @Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @QueryHints(QueryHint(name = JPA_LOCK_TIMEOUT, value = SKIP_LOCKED))
```
on a method and it translates correctly into query having `... skip locked` suffix.

Answer (score 14):

**If you are able to use Spring Data 1.6 or greater than ignore this answer and refer to Oliver's answer.**

The Spring Data pessimistic `@Lock` annotations only apply (as you pointed out) to queries.  There are not annotations I know of which can affect an entire transaction.  You can either create a `findByOnePessimistic` method which calls `findByOne` with a pessimistic lock or you can change `findByOne` to always obtain a pessimistic lock.

If you wanted to implement your own solution you probably could.  Under the hood the `@Lock` annotation is processed by `LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor` which does the following:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(method, lockMode == null ? NULL : lockMode);
```

You could create some static lock manager which had a `ThreadLocal<LockMode>` member variable and then have an aspect wrapped around every method in every repository which called `bindResource` with the lock mode set in the `ThreadLocal`.  This would allow you to set the lock mode on a per-thread basis.  You could then create your own `@MethodLockMode` annotation which would wrap the method in an aspect which sets the thread-specific lock mode before running the method and clears it after running the method.

Comment: What's the point of having a pessimistic lock on a query if it doesn't hold until the end of the transaction (and thus encompass any following updates)?

Comment: A pessimistic lock obtained in a query should hold until the end of the transaction.  Those second two paragraphs were describing how you could create a transaction where all queries obtained pessimistic locks.

Comment: If I understand correctly then, I can achieve the effect I want simply by making `findOne` use a pessimistic lock - that lock should hold until the end of my transaction (which will end at the end of my `updateWidgetStock()` method.  Is that right?

Comment: Note, that using `@Lock` will be supported on CRUD methods as of the upcoming 1.6 release of Spring Data JPA. See this [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-173) for details.