# How to specify @lock timeout in spring data jpa query?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

How to specify `@Lock` timeout for query?
I am using Oracle 11g, I hope I can use something like `'select id from table where id = ?1 for update wait 5'`.

I defined method like this:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Stock findById(String id);
```

It seems to lock forever.
When I set `javax.persistence.lock.timeout=0` in `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.jpaProperties`, there is no effect.

Answer (score 29):

> To lock entities pessimistically, set the lock mode to
>   `PESSIMISTIC_READ`, `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`, or
>   `PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT`.
>
> If a pessimistic lock cannot be obtained, but the locking failure
>   doesn’t result in a transaction rollback, a `LockTimeoutException` is
>   thrown.
>
> [**Pessimistic Locking Timeouts**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html)
>
> The length of time in milliseconds the persistence provider should
>   wait to obtain a lock on the database tables may be specified using
>   the javax.persistence.lock.timeout property. If the time it takes to
>   obtain a lock exceeds the value of this property, a
>   `LockTimeoutException` will be thrown, but the current transaction
>   will not be marked for rollback. **If this property is set to 0, the
>   persistence provider should throw a `LockTimeoutException` if it
>   cannot immediately obtain a lock.**
>
> If `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` is set in multiple places, the
>   value will be determined in the following order:
>
> 1. The argument to one of the `EntityManager` or `Query methods`.
> 2. The setting in the `@NamedQuery` annotation.
> 3. The argument to the `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` method.
> 4. The value in the `persistence.xml` deployment descriptor.

### For Spring Data 1.6 or greater

`@Lock` is supported on CRUD methods as of version 1.6 of Spring Data JPA (in fact, there's already a [milestone](http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.6.0.M1/) available). See this [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-173) for more details.

With that version you simply declare the following:

```
interface WidgetRepository extends Repository<Widget, Long> {

  @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
  Widget findOne(Long id);
}
```

This will cause the CRUD implementation part of the backing repository proxy to apply the configured LockModeType to the `find(…)` call on the `EntityManager`.

### On the other hand,

### For previous version of Spring Data 1.6

The Spring Data pessimistic `@Lock` annotations only apply (as you pointed out) to queries. There are not annotations I know of which can affect an entire transaction. You can either create a `findByOnePessimistic` method which calls `findByOne` with a pessimistic lock or you can change `findByOne` to always obtain a pessimistic lock.

If you wanted to implement your own solution you probably could. Under the hood the `@Lock` annotation is processed by `LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor` which does the following:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(method, lockMode == null ? NULL : lockMode);
```

You could create some static lock manager which had a `ThreadLocal<LockMode>` member variable and then have an aspect wrapped around every method in every repository which called bindResource with the lock mode set in the ThreadLocal. This would allow you to set the lock mode on a per-thread basis. You could then create your own `@MethodLockMode` annotation which would wrap the method in an aspect which sets the thread-specific lock mode before running the method and clears it after running the method.

### Resource Link:

1. [How to enable LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE when looking up entities with Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159396/how-to-enable-lockmodetype-pessimistic-write-when-looking-up-entities-with-sprin)
2. [How to add custom method to Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa)
3. [Spring Data Pessimistic Lock timeout with Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351470/spring-data-pessimistic-lock-timeout-with-postgres)
4. [JPA Query API](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/api)

---

### Various Example of Pessimistic Lock Timeout

### Setting a Pessimistic Lock

An entity object can be locked explicitly by the lock method:

```
em.lock(employee, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

The first argument is an entity object. The second argument is the requested lock mode.

A `TransactionRequiredException` is thrown if there is no active transaction when lock is called because explicit locking requires an active transaction.

A `LockTimeoutException` is thrown if the requested pessimistic lock cannot be granted:

- A `PESSIMISTIC_READ` lock request fails if another user (which is
  represented by another EntityManager instance) currently holds a
  `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock on that database object.
- A `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock request fails if another user currently
  holds either a `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock or a `PESSIMISTIC_READ` lock on
  that database object.

### Setting Query Hint (Scopes)

**Query hints can be set in the following scopes (from global to local):**

For the entire persistence unit - using a `persistence.xml` property:

```
<properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="3000"/>
</properties>
```

For an EntityManagerFactory - using the `createEntityManagerFacotory` method:

```
Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap();
properties.put("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 4000);
EntityManagerFactory emf =
  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu", properties);
```

For an EntityManager - using the `createEntityManager` method:

```
Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap();
properties.put("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 5000);
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(properties);
```

or using the setProperty method:

```
em.setProperty("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 6000);
```

For a `named query` definition - using the `hints` element:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Country.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Country c",
    hints={@QueryHint(name="javax.persistence.query.timeout", value="7000")})
```

For a specific query execution - using the `setHint` method (before query execution):

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 8000);
```

### Resource Link:

1. [Locking in JPA](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock)
2. [Pessimistic Lock Timeout](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/setting#Query_Hints_Execution_Timeout_and_Lock_Timeout_)

Comment: I am new to spring and only have entitymanagerfactory defined in applicationContext.xml. The timeout works well when I define it using @QueryHint annotation on each query but I want to configure it on all queries of project without annotating each query. How can I add it as a property to the entity manager factory in xml?

Answer (score 20):

You can use [`@QueryHints`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-hints) in Spring Data:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value ="5000")})
Stock findById(String id)
```

Comment: I am trying this. The first transaction is able to acquire a lock and does some processing before releasing the lock. Meanwhile, when the second transaction comes and tries to get the lock, it doesn't seem to be waiting for the time defined in value property (5000 ms in your example), rather it immediately throws exception "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet"

Comment: @old_soul_on_the_run I am running into the exact same problem as you commented, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Data 1.6 or greater,we can use @Lock annotation provided by spring data jpa.

Also, Lock time out can be set as well by using @QueryHints. Originally there was no support for query hint annotations in default CRUD methods but its been available after fix 1.6M1. 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-173

Below is an example of a Pessimistic Lock with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE mode type which is an exclusive lock.

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE) 
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value   ="5000")}) 
Customer findByCustomerId(Long customerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

javax.persistence.lock.timeout doesn't seem to be working for me also when provided like below:

```
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout",value = "15000")})
```

But then I tried something else which worked. Instead of using @Repository and using CrudRepository, now I am configuring my hbernate using entity manager. Used createQuery along with lock and setting lock timeout. And this configuration is working as expected.
I have two transaction running in parellel and trying to lock exact same row in DB. First transaction is able to acquire WRITE lock and holds the lock for around 10 secs before releasing lock. Meanwhile, second transaction tries to acquire lock on same row but since javax.persistence.lock.timeout is set to 15 secs, it waits for lock to be released and then acquires its own lock. Hence making the flow serialized.

```
@Component
public class Repository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Optional<Cache> getById(int id){
        List<Cache> list = em.createQuery("select c from Cache c where c.id = ?1")
                            .setParameter(1, id)
                            .setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 15000)
                            .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
                            .getResultList();

    
        return Optional.ofNullable(list.get(0));
    }
    
    public void save(Cache cache) {
        cache = em.find(Cache.class, cache.getId());
        em.merge(cache);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we set value of javax.persistence.lock.timeout as 300 ms or should it always be a multiple of 1000s?

Comment: Lock timeout need not necessarily be multiple of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` property is supported only by oracle provider in spring data jpa. To set a proper lock timeout you have to execute some custom native SQL statement for each DBMS provider.

Here are some DBMS specific statements to set  a lock timeout of 3 seconds:

**MySQL**

`set session innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 3`

**PostgreSQL**

`set local lock_timeout = 3000`

**SQLServer**

`set lock_timeout 3000`

See the following post for more info on the topic: https://blog.mimacom.com/handling-pessimistic-locking-jpa-oracle-mysql-postgresql-derbi-h2/