# Spring data CrudRepository and pessimistic lock

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using

- Spring Boot 1.4.2
- Spring Data JPA 1.10.5
- PostgreSQL 9.5 database

I want to have a `findOne` method with pessimistic lock in my Spring Data repository that is separate from the `findOne` method that is already provided.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32315795/1448419) I wrote:

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends CrudRepository<Registration, Long> {
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("select r from Registration r where r.id = ?1")
    Registration findOnePessimistic(Long id);
}
```

This almost works.

Unfortunately, this does not refresh previous instance of my entity in the entity manager cache. I have two concurrent requests updating the status of my registration

- the second one waits for the transaction of the first one to commit
- the second one does **not** take into account the changes made by the first one.

Hence broken behavior.

Any clue why `@Lock` does not out of the box refresh the entity manager?

*Update*

Here is the requested example code:

```
public interface RegistrationRepository extends CrudRepository<Registration, Long> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("select r from registration_table r where r.id = ?1")
    Registration findOnePessimistic(Long id);

}

public void RegistrationService {

    @Transactional
    public void doSomething(long id){
        // Both threads read the same version of the data 
        Registration registrationQueriedTheFirstTime = registrationRepository.findOne(id);

        // First thread gets the lock, second thread waits for the first thread to have committed
        Registration registration = registrationRepository.findOnePessimistic(id);
        // I need this to have this statement, otherwise, registration.getStatus() contains the value not yet updated by the first thread
        entityManager.refresh(registration);

        registration.setStatus(newStatus);
        registrationRepository.save(registration);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to show us the code, which changes the entity-value. Why do you lock the table with 'PESSIMISTIC_WRITE' on a method which only read the entity?

Comment: I use the code in a method annotated `@Transactional`, where I read the entity, update it, and write it back. Quite standard. I want to avoid concurrency on this operation, so I want to use a pessimistic lock. I just want to do the `select for update` before the `update`.

Comment: The whole code block is transactional, and thus uses the same entitymanager. The `EntityManager` acts as the first level cache. You first retrieve the object without a lock, to retrieve it right again with a lock. But du to the first level cache you will retrieve that object instead of a fresh DB object. That is basically how the `EntityManager` works, if you don't want that you first have to `clear` the entity manager. Or rather why do you first retrieve it without a lock in the same tx (which is weird imho).

Comment: I would expect `CrudRepository` to clear that entity from the first level cache in case I specify pessimistic lock ...

Comment: You don't need the first fetching. Delete it. Do you have any second-level cache control on your Registration entities?

Comment: I know by experience how hard is concurrency handling in online registrations, just wondering why you use pessimistic locking instead of optimistic. Are you trying to fix a double submit / two windows open problem ?

Comment: The question is not about how relevant pessimistic locking is in my case, the question is about why Spring-Data-JPA does not refresh the cache with the value locked in DB ... FYI I use pessimistic locking because have side effects to my status update (e.g. sending emails) that cannot be rolled back.

Comment: @rcomblen maybe you had configured REPEATABLE_READ as DB transaction level?

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the `entityManger transaction` that `Spring` creates for you :

```
    @Transactional
    public void doSomething(long id){
        // Both threads read the same version of the data 
        Registration registrationQueriedTheFirstTime = registrationRepository.findOne(id);

        // First thread gets the lock, second thread waits for the first thread to have committed
        Registration registration = registrationRepository.findOnePessimistic(id);
        // I need this to have this statement, otherwise, registration.getStatus() contains the value not yet updated by the first thread
        entityManager.refresh(registration);

        EntityManager em = EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(<Your entity manager factory>);
        em.refresh(registration);
        registration.setStatus(newStatus);
        registrationRepository.save(registration);
    }

}
```

Comment: If I use `entityManager.refresh` it just works fine. I would just expect that I would NOT need that. That code is running fine in production right now.

Comment: @RahulGupta it seems there is no problem, rcomblen is just curios about why he has to manually refresh