# Java JPA and Services, how to prevent a Read from running during an Insert to the same Entity

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, transactions, entity

I have 2 threads calling the same service with potentially the same data that needs to be inserted into a table if not present.

I have a bulk call like this:

```
@Async
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, timeout=100)
    public void adoptDealInBulk(List<String> adopters, ....)
```

This in turn does a loop for each to the adoptDeal call.

```
@Transactional(timeout=20)
adoptDeal(adopter)
```

This does a look up first to see if an adoption was created:

```
 adoptionService.findAdoption(adopter)
```

....
and if not present a create and save:
...

```
repository.save(adoption);
```

This is the read to find the adoption:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
findAdoption(adoption)
```

Now I've tried on the adoptDeal call:

```
@Transactional(timeout=Constant.ADOPT_OFFER_TIMEOUT, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

And on the findAdoption

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

I know its terrible for performance, but shouldn't this prevent the read while the other thread is doing the insert?

However, I still get dupe rows with 2 threads hit this with the same new user to add.

How could I fix the annotations or add something else to prevent the read and also commit one at a time?

Thank you.

Comment: Try locking mechanisms:
https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/01/12/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/

Sample:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159396/how-to-enable-lockmodetype-pessimistic-write-when-looking-up-entities-with-sprin

Comment: Your database should protect against this.