# Overloading query in jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am looking for a way to overload several queries from my jpa repository. 
for example i want to have the "regular" :    `public Player findPlayerById(Long Id);`
but also :

```
 @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    public Player findPlayerById(Long Id);
```

I found this: [How to add custom method to Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa)
but i don't think its relevant for my case. 
I thought about creating PlayerRepositoryPessimestic with the locked annotation.

Is there a way to use the same repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here your problem is more a `Java` problem.

Both

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
public Player findPlayerById(Long Id);
```

and

```
public Player findPlayerById(Long Id);
```

have the same signature. So my guess is that it is not possible using the same repo. But there are plenty options. Different repos as you suggest is the easiest one IMO. But you could write a custom `InvocationHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! i'm going for the easy way :)