# Spring Data JPA SubQuery

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I´m in a situation where I have two entities, let´s say A and B, in B I have a relationship ManyToOne with A.But in A I dont have the oneToMany. I´m using Spring-Data repositories, and I was wondering If would be possible make a subQuery using Query annotation. 
So far I see some example of people using CriteriaQuery, but always with JOIN example, and in my case I need the other way around. I need to find all A´s if their id´s are not in B.
Any good and elegant solutions?.

Comment: You can use the classic fallback way, in a custom DAO class.

Comment: I was looking for a Spring data solution, but thanks

Comment: I only want to give you the pointer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa - if you know this, than everything is right.

Comment: Yeah it´s just what I´m tryinng but give me some  error becuase the syntax. I have this so far, would be possible?.. @Query(value="SELECT * FROM publication_request WHERE publication_date < :publicationDate AND id NOT IN(SELECT publication_request_id FROM enotification_log)")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `@Query` on your interface methods and write your JPQL there. Examples here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-querylanguage005.htm#BNBVL

e.g.
`SELECT DISTINCT a FROM A a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT b FROM B b WHERE <<put your condition here>>)`

Comment: can I use this syntax in Spring data repository?. I will try.

Comment: Yep - in the repository

Comment: Sorry but I could not make it works. In my case I canot use the not exist because I dont have any condition. I just want make the typical find if id not exist in another table.   @Query(value="SELECT * FROM publication_request WHERE publication_date < :publicationDate AND id NOT IN(SELECT publication_request_id FROM enotification_log)")     This is what I have so far

Comment: JPQL isn't SQL. I assumed from you question that both `publication_request` and `enotification_log` have mapped entities ("A" and "B" in your question). Your query needs to use those and not raw SQL. Then read up on JPQL - the solution I gave you should work. I gave a link to Java 6 JPQL though so here's Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-querylanguage.htm

Comment: Yep mu fault, I was using by mistake SQL table names instead entity names :(

Comment: Glad you worked it out - can you please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NamedNativeQuery** of JPA or custom pojo class (with constructor to populate all your required field) but in this case you will get array of object and you have to fech your records from object array.