# Spring Data JPA - While saving duplicate Composite Key doesn't get any error

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am developing **Spring Boot JPA Composite key example using Postgres**. In this example, when I'm trying to save record, why I dont see any exceptions or constraint violation exception?

**SongId.java**

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class SongId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private String album;
    private String artist;
}
```

Song.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Song {
    @EmbeddedId 
    private SongId id;

    private int duration;
    private String genre;
    private LocalDateTime releaseDate;
    private int rating;
    private String downloadUrl;
}
```

**SongsRepository.java**

```
public interface SongsRepository extends JpaRepository<Song, Long>{

}
```

MainApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CompositeApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CompositeApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Autowired
    private SongsRepository repo;


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        SongId songId1 = SongId.builder().name("John").album("AlbumA").artist("ArtistA").build();

        Song song = Song.builder().id(songId1).downloadUrl("http://www.gmail.com").duration(23)
                .genre("MyGene").rating(1).releaseDate(LocalDateTime.now()).build();
        Song song2 = Song.builder().id(songId1).downloadUrl("http://www.gmail.com").duration(23)
                .genre("MyGene").rating(1).releaseDate(LocalDateTime.now()).build();

        try {
            repo.saveAll(Arrays.asList(song, song2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

***Edit-1:***
I changed **SongsRepository.java** to

```
public interface SongsRepository extends CrudRepository<Song, SongId>{}
```

and main Method code.

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        SongId songId1 = SongId.builder().name("John").album("AlbumA").artist("ArtistA").build();

        Song song = Song.builder().songId(songId1).downloadUrl("http://www.gmail.com").duration(23)
                .genre("MyGene").rating(4).releaseDate(LocalDateTime.now()).build();
        Song song2 = Song.builder().songId(songId1).downloadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com").duration(25)
                .genre("Sample Testung").rating(2).releaseDate(LocalDateTime.now()).build();

        repo.saveAll(Arrays.asList(song, song2));

    }
```

**Logs:**

```
2019-07-03 19:56:31.901  INFO 5420 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-07-03 19:56:32.265  INFO 5420 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-07-03 19:56:32.378  INFO 5420 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-07-03 19:56:32.415  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-07-03 19:56:32.466  INFO 5420 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-07-03 19:56:32.467  INFO 5420 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-07-03 19:56:32.600  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-07-03 19:56:32.747  INFO 5420 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2019-07-03 19:56:32.895  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2019-07-03 19:56:32.899  INFO 5420 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@4ad3d266
Hibernate: 

    drop table if exists composite.song cascade
Hibernate: 

    create table composite.song (
       album varchar(255) not null,
        artist varchar(255) not null,
        name varchar(255) not null,
        download_url varchar(255),
        duration int4 not null,
        genre varchar(255),
        rating int4 not null,
        release_date timestamp,
        primary key (album, artist, name)
    )
2019-07-03 19:56:33.350  INFO 5420 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@41ad373'
2019-07-03 19:56:33.352  INFO 5420 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-07-03 19:56:33.404 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] .c.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean : Initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext…
2019-07-03 19:56:33.410 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] .c.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean : Finished initializing JpaMetamodelMappingContext!
2019-07-03 19:56:33.557 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.c.s.RepositoryFactorySupport     : Initializing repository instance for com.example.repository.SongsRepository…
2019-07-03 19:56:33.603 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] o.s.d.j.r.query.JpaQueryFactory          : Looking up query for method findBySongId_AlbumAndSongId_ArtistAndSongId_Name
2019-07-03 19:56:33.604 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery    : Looking up named query Song.findBySongId_AlbumAndSongId_ArtistAndSongId_Name
2019-07-03 19:56:33.606 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] o.s.d.jpa.repository.query.NamedQuery    : Did not find named query Song.findBySongId_AlbumAndSongId_ArtistAndSongId_Name
2019-07-03 19:56:33.646 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.c.s.RepositoryFactorySupport     : Finished creation of repository instance for com.example.repository.SongsRepository.
2019-07-03 19:56:33.713  INFO 5420 --- [           main] com.example.CompositeApplication         : Started CompositeApplication in 2.59 seconds (JVM running for 3.333)
2019-07-03 19:56:33.722 DEBUG 5420 --- [           main] stomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method 'saveAll' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
Hibernate: 
    select
        song0_.album as album1_0_0_,
        song0_.artist as artist2_0_0_,
        song0_.name as name3_0_0_,
        song0_.download_url as download4_0_0_,
        song0_.duration as duration5_0_0_,
        song0_.genre as genre6_0_0_,
        song0_.rating as rating7_0_0_,
        song0_.release_date as release_8_0_0_ 
    from
        composite.song song0_ 
    where
        song0_.album=? 
        and song0_.artist=? 
        and song0_.name=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        composite.song
        (download_url, duration, genre, rating, release_date, album, artist, name) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    update
        composite.song 
    set
        download_url=?,
        duration=?,
        genre=?,
        rating=?,
        release_date=? 
    where
        album=? 
        and artist=? 
        and name=?
2019-07-03 19:56:33.773  INFO 5420 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-07-03 19:56:33.776  INFO 5420 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-07-03 19:56:33.779  INFO 5420 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: You defined your key as a `Long` according to your repository interface. Instead it should be the proper type. Next to that you are inserting the exact same and due to the generated equals/hashcode hibernate will detect this as the same entity and discard one. Change some of the properties of entity 2 (not those that make up the key) which shouls make it fail.

Comment: Which is because eventually a `merge` is being done. The default `isNew` check checks if the id is `null`. In your case it isn't, hence it will lead to a merge, and thus an update for the second entity instead of a new one.

Comment: @M.Deinum - You're right. Merge is happening after checking `isNew`. Can you guide me how to fixed this issue now ?

Comment: Can you please share the stacktrace for logs

Comment: @Mayur Jain - Added logs

Comment: *Can you guide me how to fixed this issue now?* What do you perceive the issue to be?

Comment: I also not getting the error in the same scenario I am also using composite keys

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
public interface SongsRepository extends JpaRepository<Song, Long>
```

to

```
public interface SongsRepository extends JpaRepository<Song, SongId>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Could you please give a try ? Is this bug ?

Comment: If this did not help, there is the most probably problem in your database. Are you sure your `name`, `album` and `artist` columns are part of the primary key? Looks like a strange combination to use as a primary key to me.

Comment: This works now, I am so sorry that I had change `JpaRepository` to `CrudRepository`

Comment: That's good, but however, your `song` table seems like a very bad example of database normalization. Just create and `artist` and `album` tables with id and name and reference them as foreign keys in your `song` table with the song identifiable by and id. Just a simple example, consider you want to find exactly one song, you need to know the name, who the author is and which album contains it.

Comment: But I have to put `@PrePersist
 public void initIdentifier(SongId songId1) {
  if (songId == null) {
   this.songId = songId1;
  }
 }` at songs model class, if I dont put that data gets saved . Do you know why ?

Comment: I have no idea why. But seems like not a good approach? You set the id and then it gets overwritten by entity mapping (when using select).

Comment: I don't get why you need to do that, but seems like an another question to ask.

Comment: Like I said, make sure you follow relational database principes and it will work just fine. Normalize your database columns and try that.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Jpa Repository functionality is implemented via the SimpleJpaRepository class containing following save(..) method:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Thus the Spring Jpa Data Repository save(...) method merges an already existing entity.

Opposed to that the naked EntityManager#persist() throws an exception if invoked with already existing entity.

The problem might be solved by adding custom behavior to Spring Data Repository/ies.

Alternatively : you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175527/11148688)

The easiest (and least invasive) way to work around this is probably by making sure the id only gets set right before the persist. This can be achieved in a @PrePersist callback:

```
@Data
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    public class Song {
        @EmbeddedId
        private SongId id;

        private int duration;
        private String genre;
        private LocalDateTime releaseDate;
        private int rating;
        private String downloadUrl;

    @PrePersist
    void initIdentifier() {
        SongId songId1 = SongId.builder().name("John").album("AlbumA").artist("ArtistA").build();
        if (id == null) {
            this.id = … songId1 // Create ID instance here.
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You might extend your spring data jpa repository/ repositories with custom persist() method and implement it via EntityManager#persist(), the EntityManager can be injected into the implementation class of the custom method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27151125/spring-data-jpa-composite-key-duplicate-key-record-insertion-resulting-in-update

Comment: Set the SongId object inside initIdentifier() only. Don't set the id at the time of  build the song.

Comment: I am not sure how to actually set the SongId object inside initIdentifier(). Can you please show some code? That will really help. Thanks!

Comment: Actually not clear on ``// Create ID instance here.``, how to set this from main method

Comment: I dont think we can keep creating instance like this where we have so many create request. How everytime we will pass SongId instance to ``void initIdentifier()``, do you think this is good approach ?

Comment: `@PrePersist` is a method which is executed before persisting the entity and should be definitely not used for that purpose. Rather a constructor argument of type `SongId` should be made which will be assigned to an `id` attribute.