# How to reference the 'normal' spring data repo from a custom implementation?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to extend a `JpaRepository` with a custom implementation, so i add a `MyRepositoryCustom` interface and a `MyRepositoryImpl` class extending this interface.

Is there a way to call methods from `JpaRepository` inside my custom class?

Note: This was also asked as a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881203/40064, but I think it is common enough to deserve a separate question.

Comment: We generally recommend not to extend `JpaRepository` as it exposes store specific API which clients usually shouldn't be aware of.

Comment: I agree, I use `CrudRepository` as much as possible, but this is a migration project, so sometimes I need some things from `JpaRepository`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### tl;dr

To inject the core repository interface into a custom implementation, inject a `Provider<RepositoryInterface>` into the custom implementation.

### Details

The core challenge to get that working is setting up the dependency injection correctly as you are about to create a cyclic dependency between the object you're about to extend and the extension. However this can be solved as follows:

```
interface MyRepository extends Repository<DomainType, Long>, MyRepositoryCustom {
  // Query methods go here
}

interface MyRepositoryCustom {
  // Custom implementation method declarations go here
}

class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepositoryCustom {

  private final Provider<MyRepository> repository;

  @Autowired
  public MyRepositoryImpl(Provider<MyRepository> repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  // Implement custom methods here
}
```

The most important part here is using `Provider<MyRepository>` which will cause Spring to create a lazily-initialized proxy for that dependency *even while it's creating an instance for `MyRepository` in the first place*. Inside the implementation of your custom methods you can then access the actual bean using the `….get()`-method.

`Provider` is an interface from the `@Inject` JSR and thus a standardized interface and requires an additional dependency to that API JAR. If you want to stick to Spring only, you can used `ObjectFactory` as an alternative interface but get the very same behavior.

Comment: I guess `MyCustomRepository` should be `MyRepositoryCustom` ? Also `Repository` takes 2 arguments. I am well aware you know this, but it would make the answer more complete for others who stumble upon it :)

Comment: I've fixed the type signature as you expected. There's no draw back in Manish's answer, it's a completely different purpose. His answer targets all repositories (which you indicated you didn't want and let me add my answer in the first place). Plus, in my use case you get access to the entire repository, not only `SimpleJpaRepository`.

Comment: Would it be possible to support this by allowing to make `MyRepositoryImpl` abstract? I don't know if spring data could take that abstract class and "add" the implementations of the CrudRepo to it? It would avoid the workaround with `Provider`

Comment: Thanks Oliver. This should be part of the official documentation, I was looking for this since monthes.

Comment: What package is Provider in? Every library has its own Provider class. It this javax.inject.Provider?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Abstract classes require a subclass to implement the missing behaviour so that it can be instantiated. I am super sure you know this by now, just if someone stumbles upon this as me ;D

Answer (score 1):

The section titled [Adding custom behaviour to all repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) in the documentation should help you.

For example (only for illustration purposes):

```
public interface ExtendedJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
       extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    T findFirst();
    T findLast();
}

public class ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
       extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>
       implements ExtendedJpaRepository<T, ID> {
  public ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
    super(domainClass, entityManager);
  }

  public T findFirst() {
    List<T> all = findAll();

    return !all.isEmpty() ? all.get(0) : null;
  }

  public T findLast() {
    List<T> all = findAll();

    return !all.isEmpty() ? all.get(all.size() - 1) : null;
  }
}
```

Then, configure `ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl` for use as per the instructions given in the documentation linked above.

Since `ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl` extends `SimpleJpaRepository` (which is an implementation of `JpaRepository`), all methods from `JpaRepository` can be called from `ExtendedJpaRepositoryImpl`.

Comment: I don't want to add this to all my repositories. Will this work for just one repository?

Comment: Yes, just refer to the section above the one I have linked to.