# How to extract "find or create" method to abstract class? (Spring Data Jpa)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I'm using Spring Data JPA and I have a bunch of repositories like this one:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {}
```

Under repositories I have services and a lot of them need to have implemented method findOrCreate(String name) like this one:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> findOrCreate(final String name) {
        checkNotNull(name);
        List<Customer> result = this.customerRepository.findByName(name);
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.info("Cannot find customer. Creating a new customer. [name={}]", name);
            Customer customer = new Customer(name);
            return Arrays.asList(this.customerRepository.save(customer));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I would like to extract method to the abstract class or somewhere to avoid implementing it for each services, testing and so on.

Abstract class can be look like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractManagementService<T, R extends JpaRepository<T, Serializable>> {

    protected List<T> findOrCreate(T entity, R repository) {
        checkNotNull(entity);
        checkNotNull(repository);

        return null;
    }

}
```

And the problem is it due to the fact that I need to find object by name as a string before creating a new one. Of course interface JpaRepository doesn't offer this method.

How can I solve this problem?

Best Regards

Comment: There is a race condition here: when this method is called from two threads on an entity that has not yet been created. Both will try to fetch (and won't find anything), then one of the `save()` will fail.

Comment: I don't think there is, because both statements are executed in a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [custom JpaRepository implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) that includes this behaviour.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361275/how-to-reference-the-normal-spring-data-repo-from-a-custom-implementation/28368972#28368972) for an example of writing a custom JpaRepository implementation.

Comment: I did like you said. According to the post. Works well. Thanks!