# Use repository method in custom repository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I check documentation of spring for doing custom method

```
interface UserRepositoryCustom {
  public void someCustomMethod(User user);
}

class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

  public void someCustomMethod(User user) {
    // Your custom implementation
  }
}
```

What is need to do if i need to use some standard rempository method (find, delete...) in UserRepositoryImpl?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference the 'normal' spring data repo from a custom implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361275/how-to-reference-the-normal-spring-data-repo-from-a-custom-implementation)

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 0):

I think to inject a standard repo:

```java
@Repository
class CrudRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

  @Autoware 
  private JpaRepository<User, Long> userRepo;

  public void someCustomMethod(User user) {

    // Your custom implementation

    userRepo.save(user);
  }
}
```

[The prove](https://github.com/Cepr0/custom-repo/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/cepr0/demo/CustomRepoImplTest.java).