# Spring JPA Repository dynamic query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Currently I have been using following Spring JPA Repository base custom query and it works fine,

```
 @Query("SELECT usr FROM User usr  WHERE usr.configurable = TRUE "
              + "AND (" +
                        "lower(usr.name) like lower(:filterText) OR lower(usr.userType.classType.displayName) like lower(:filterText) OR lower(usr.userType.model) like lower(:filterText)"
              +      ")"
              + "")
  public List<User> findByFilterText(@Param("filterText") String filterText, Sort sort);
```

I need to modify this query when filter text going to be a comma separated value. But as following manner it will be a dynamic query and how can I execute it.

Dynamic query I need to build,

```
String sql = "SELECT usr FROM User usr WHERE usr.configurable = TRUE";

for(String word : filterText.split(",")) {
                sql += " AND (lower(usr.name) like lower(:" + word + ") OR lower(usr.userType.classType.displayName) like lower(:" + word + ") OR lower(usr.userType.model) like lower(:" + word + "))";
}
```

Comment: look into `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

Comment: Provide an implementation for your DAO, and execute this dynamic query from the implementation. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour. The DAO shouldn't split. It should take a List<String> or a Set<String> as argument. The caller should deal with splitting.

Answer (score 20):

Per JB Nizet and the [spring-data documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour), you should use a custom interface + repository implementation.

Create an interface with the method:

```
public interface MyEntityRepositoryCustom {
    List<User> findByFilterText(Set<String> words);
}
```

Create an implementation:

```
@Repository
public class MyEntityRepositoryImpl implements MyEntityRepositoryCustom {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<User> findByFilterText(Set<String> words) {
        // implementation below
    }
}
```

Extend the new interface in your existing Repository interface:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, MyEntityRepositoryCustom {
    // other query methods
}
```

Finally, call the method somewhere else:

```
dao.findByFilterText(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(filterText.split(","))));
```

**Query implementation**

Your method of producing the `sql` variable, namely by concatenating some strings into the query is bad. **Do not do this.**

The `word` which you are concatenating must be a [valid JPQL identifier](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_named_params), namely a `:` followed by a [java identifier start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart%28int%29), optionally followed by some [java identifier part](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart%28int%29). This means that if your CSV contains `foo bar,baz`, you will attempt to use `foo bar` as an identifier and you'll get an exception.

You can instead use [`CriteriaBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) to construct the query in a safe way:

```
public List<User> findByFilterText(Set<String> words) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> q = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> user = q.from(User.class);

    Path<String> namePath = user.get("name");
    Path<String> userTypeClassTypeDisplayName = 
                     user.get("userType").get("classType").get("displayName");
    Path<String> userTypeModel = user.get("userType").get("model");
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String word : words) {
        Expression<String> wordLiteral = cb.literal(word);
        predicates.add(
                cb.or(
                    cb.like(cb.lower(namePath), cb.lower(wordLiteral)),
                    cb.like(cb.lower(userTypeClassTypeDisplayName),
                            cb.lower(wordLiteral)),
                    cb.like(cb.lower(userTypeModel), cb.lower(wordLiteral))
                )
        );
    }
    q.select(doc).where(
            cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]))
    );

    return entityManager.createQuery(q).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your worth full answer. 

Due to compiler failure I have apply following corrections,
cb.lower(word) --> cb.lower(wordLiteral )
q.select(doc) --> q.select(user)

But with those corrections when I implement this solution I will get following error on application deploy time:-  

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property filter found for type com.ord.model.User

Comment: @Channa Fixed. It sounds like spring-data is trying to interpret the function name `findByFilterText`, which it shouldn't be doing. Did you make your repository extend the custom repository class?

Comment: Yes I have done the things as you mention. That mean I have created "MyEntityRepositoryCustom" interface and then later extend it to existing Repository Interface as "public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, MyEntityRepositoryCustom"

Comment: @Channa I had an error in the repository name, it must be `MyEntityRepositoryImpl`, not `MyEntityRepositoryCustomImpl`. See if making that change helps.

Comment: thanks for feedback. I have done the change as you mention, but still I am getting same exception :(. Have a nice time !. Thanks.

Comment: Can I implement this in case my query is a complex one? i.e- It includes `JOINS` and `subqueries`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266362/add-dynamic-criteria-to-a-jpa-custom-query

Comment: createQuery Does it support true paging ?  （like mysql limit 0,10）

Answer (score 8):

I've been looking for the solution myself :
The naming of the "Custom" repository interface and implentation is very strict (as said there [How to add custom method to Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa))

So, to be clear, the whole code :
(But @beerbajay was right)

The custom method interface

```
public interface MyEntityRepositoryCustom {
    List<MyEntity> findSpecial();
}
```

The custom method implementation

```
public class MyEntityRepositoryImpl implements MyEntityRepositoryCustom {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    //custom method implementation
    public List<Object> findSpecial() {
        List<Object> list = em.createNativeQuery("select name, value from T_MY_ENTITY").getResultList();
        return list;
    }
}
```

The "original" repository

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity,Long>, MyEntityRepositoryCustom {
    //original methods here... do not redefine findSpecial()...
}
```

You can now use the "original" repository with the new custom methods

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private DataRepository r;

    public void doStuff() {
        List<Object> list = r.findSpecial();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring Data JPA has a way to create Custom and Dynamic queries with "Specifications":
[Spring Data - Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

First, your interface which extends `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository` should also implement `JpaSpecificationExecutor<...>` and that's all you need.
Your repository now has a new method `findAll` which accepts a `Specification<...>` object, and your can use the method Beerbajay used to create Criteria Queries by overriding the method `toPredicate(...)` and there you are free to build (almost) any query you want like so:

```js
Specification<...> spec = new Specification<...>() {
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<...> entity, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {                
    List<Predicate> conditions = buildManyPredicates(cb, entity);
    return cb.and(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[conditions.size()]));
}
 };

repository.findAll(spec, PageRequest.of(0, 10));
```

This solves the problem of Spring Data trying to parse the methods you added in the custom interface (because there is no custom interface)

Comment: Cannot be paired with custom queries

Comment: you can build whatever query you want using predicates and the criteria builder.

Answer (score 0):

try query DSL as illustrated in the [official documents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)