# Add dynamic criteria to a JPA custom Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a complex query(using multiple joins and subqueries) written in HQL which I have used in a Repository class. Similar to one below -

```
@Repository
public interface DataRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Data,String> {

    public List<Data> findByService(@Param("service")Service service, Pageable page);

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT d from Data d "
            +" WHERE (d.working in (SELECT d1 from Data d1 "
                +" JOIN d1.working d1w "
                +" JOIN d1.service s WITH (s in (:serviceList)))"
            +" OR d.cleared IS NOT NULL) AND [..several other CRITERIA]")
    public Page<Data> findForServices(@Param("serviceList")Set<Service> serviceList, Pageable page);
....
```

Now I need to add criteria to it dynamically. These criteria are flexible in number which is holding me from including it into the `HQL` straightaway. Is it anyhow possible?

Sifting through the internet I have come across solutions for [dynamic query](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/). But, I guess they would be working only for cases where I do not have a custom query i.e.- no `@Query` at the query in the `repository`.

There was another [interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431035/spring-jpa-repository-dynamic-query) I found. But that also suits for a case where you have a single table to query.

I do not want to be switching over to raw SQL queries. How do I solve this?

Comment: Is it not possible to convert to `CriteriaQuery` that would be easy to construct dynamically? I am a bit sceptic about other possibilities. What exactly you meant _But that also suits for a case where you have a single table to query_? Maybe problems with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30436524/6413377?

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned Criteria API with specifications and predicates is a little bit difficult to get used to but it is a good way to handle dynamic conditions. 
I don't think it is possible to mix the annotation based query with programmatic query creation.