# How to put method to @Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-el

there is typical jpa interface

```
public interface AnswerPollsRepository extends JpaRepository<EAnswerPoll, Long>{

default String getQuery(Map<String,String>map,Long pollId){
    String sql="select a.* from answer_poll a where a.poll_id ="+pollId;
  return sql+map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(x->!x.getKey().equals("mail")&&x.getKey().equals("name"))
        .map(x->"and a.parameters->>"+x.getKey()+" like "+x.getValue())
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

 @Query( value = "#{@.getQuery(#id,#map)}" ,nativeQuery = true)
  List<Long>findAllByCustomFilter(@Param("id") Long pollId,@Param("map") Map<String,String>map);
```

how to put getQuery to @Query?or it is impossible?
this does not work

```
@Query( value = "#{@.getQuery(#id,#map)}" ,nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: For now, spring does not accept such uses in the `@Query` annotation, so you cannot use it that way. **You need to do it by creating a custom repository.** See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431035/spring-jpa-repository-dynamic-query

Comment: thank you ,too bad that it  is not aviable now