# Partially implemented repository with Spring data Neo4j 4

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm trying to partially implement a repository using the following structure:

```
public interface ExampleCustomRepository {
    Iterable<Example> findExamplesByUserId(Long id);
}

@Repository
@Transactional
public class ExampleCustomRepositoryImpl implements ExampleCustomRepository {
    @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate template;

    @Override
    public Iterable<Example> findExamplesByUserId(final Long id) {
        // implementation
    }
}

public interface ExampleRepository extends GraphRepository<Example>, ExampleCustomRepository {
}
```

For some reason the `RepositoryFactory` wants to create a `DerivedGraphRepositoryQuery` for this implemented method, and fails:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property userId found for type Example!
```

Is it even possible to partially implement a repository with SDN4? If it is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your class Example has property UserId? And how does the last line even compile?

Comment: No, the Eaxmple class does not have userId, but it has a relationship to a user (which has). Which last line?

Comment: `public interface ExampleRepository extends GraphRepository<Example>, ExampleCustomRepository {
}`

Comment: Did you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa

Comment: @jny that question did not came up when I searched for an answer, and it actually helped. I overlooked the naming convention. If you add an answer based on that, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the naming convention, which was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa).

I had too rename `ExampleCustomRepositoryImpl` to `ExampleRepositoryImpl`.