# How to make Oracle JDBC connection and execute queries in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-boot

I didn't get a clear picture on making a Oracle JDBC connection in Spring Boot and executing the queries. Can someone please help me or guide me regarding this issue?

Answer (score 3):

First at all you will need the oracle jdbc driver as maven/gradle dependency. Oracle does not have its driver in the public repository. So you need to download the jdbc driver from oracle and install this jar into a maven dependency.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar  -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Or you can go to the [oracle specific maven repository](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) and get the stuff from there.

After that you are able to add this dependency to your pom.xml of your application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

On the https://start.spring.io/ website you can create a brand new application. For the start I would choose `Web` and `JPA`.

Now in the application.properties file you can set your jdbc configurations:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:yourUrl
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

After that you should be able to start and run the application.

For more you should read docs for [Springs repositories](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/), [custom queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34307045/3493036), [custom entity manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074547/spring-boot-configure-entitymanager)

Comment: How and where should I write the oracle sql queries after the database configuration

Comment: @Patrick, Oracle JDBC drivers are available on oracle maven repository.  Please refer to this blog (https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides) for more details.

Comment: @VarunShet please see the provided docs in my answer. There are different easy ways to create sql queries. you should read first the repository stuff