# Custom repository not working in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to add custom repository methods in Spring as show in the documentation here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

and in a Stack Overflow question here:

[How to add custom method to Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa)

and it's not working as expected.

I took the repository, defined as:

```
public interface ScreenshotRepository extends JpaRepository<Screenshot, UUID> {
```

and changed it to

```
public interface ScreenshotRepository extends JpaRepository<Screenshot, UUID>, ScreenshotRepositoryCustom {
```

Then I created the `ScreenshotRepositoryCustom` interface:

```
interface ScreenshotRepositoryCustom {
    void foo();
}
```

and the implementation:

```
class ScreenshotRepositoryCustomImpl implements ScreenshotRepositoryCustom {
    @Override
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Foo!!!");
    }
}
```

When I try to start the spring application, I get this message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'screenshotRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property foo found for type Screenshot!
```

which I'm having trouble understanding. What's going on here?

Comment: You should also post your Screenshot class as this is the one missing the property foo.

Comment: I don't see any annotations on `ScreenshotRepositoryCustomImpl`. It should be a bean.

Comment: @java-addict301: the Screenshot class doesn't have and shouldn't have a foo member. The problem was strictly on the repositories and the answer I was pointed to actually contained the solution.

Comment: @IlyaNovoseltsev: I do get a warning from IntelliJ about that. How do I make it a bean? I tried @ Repository (as well as others) and all of those cause one error or another.

Comment: @Pablo Hector marked this question as a duplicate and there is a correct answer in his link. You have to name your class `ScreenshotRepositoryImpl` without `Custom` and, yes, make it a `@Repository`. Interface should remain `ScreenshotRepositoryCustom `. That is a correct setup.

Comment: @IlyaNovoseltsev: it's not working for me, I posted another question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455561/how-to-annotate-a-custom-spring-boot-custom-repository