# When I try delete a entity with Hibernate, there isn't a error message but doesn't delete

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three entities, `Bag`, `Item` and `Category`. One `Bag` can have Many `Items` and Many `Items` can have Many `Categories`:

`Bag` <----`OneToMany`----> `Item`

`Item` -----`ManyToMany`-----> `Category`

It isn't necessary store `items` in `Category`

When I try delete a `Item` without `categories`, there isn't any error message, but the `Item` isn't deleted. However if i try delete the same `item` in DataBase, it is deleted successfully.

On the other hand, if i try delete a `Item` with `categories`, i receive this error message:

"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`item_categories`, CONSTRAINT `fk_item_categories_items_id` FOREIGN KEY (`items_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`id`))".

I would like delete the `item` and the relation with his `categories`, but keep `categories`. How could I do this?

For the first problem, I have tried add to the delete method `bag.removeItems(item)`, but it only deletes tthe relationship between both and the `item` continues in DB.

> Bag.java

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("bag")
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();
```

> Item.java

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("items")
    private Bag bag;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "item_categories",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="items_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="categories_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
```

> ItemResource.java

```
    @DeleteMapping("/items/{id}")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteItem(@PathVariable Long id) {
        itemRepository.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
The methods of create and update works fine.

Comment: Please also post Category.java

Comment: Category.java doesn't have any relation, only have attributes, that's why I did not post it

Comment: you're not doing category.getItems() then?

Comment: No, because my app will not have that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that you a many-to-many relation which is solved by intermediate (or association) table, where the pairs item - category are stored.
When you delete the Item, an actual `DELETE FROM item` query is executed, but it fails since there is a foreign key constraint which won't allow the corresponding pairs to remain orphaned.

To solve this you can simply remove the associations yourself:

```
item.getCategories().clear();
```

As to where this code has to be executed, it's up to you. You can create a hook inside Item, like so:

```
@PreRemove
private void deleteCategories() {
    this.getCategories().clear();
}
```

Or you could create an ItemService which would do something like

```
public void deleteItem(Long id) {
    final Item item = itemRepository.findById(id);
    // you can handle here when not found, which is a good thing to do
    item.getCategories().clear();
    itemRepository.deleteItem(item);
}
```

Or you could implement a custom method for JPA repository, which I don't like, but you can read up on that here [How to add custom method to Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa).

Comment: Works!! I have opted for method in the service and allright. Any idea for the problem between `Bag` and `Item`?

Comment: @CodificadorD sorry, what's the problem with Bag? You want to delete Item and keep Bag or what?

Comment: Ok, I just solved it based on your answer. I add on `deleteItem` method: `final Bag b = item.getBag();
  b.removeItems(item);` I had tried it before and it did not work, but now yes

Comment: Thank you so much for everything @Nestor-sokil

Comment: @CodificadorD you're welcome. Please note there is an option to use orphanRemoval = true in OneToMany relations, which allows you to skip explicit delete for child items. You can check it out here https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/