# JPA result set mapping to new object

Tags: java, jpa

```java
public interface ScheduleRepository extends JpaRepository<Schedule, Long> {

@Query(value = "select * from truck t, " +
           "(select  day, end_time, latitude, longitude, start_time, " +
           "truckid, is_open from schedule) s where s.truckid = t.id and day = :today ;"
           , nativeQuery = true)
List<TruckLocation> getTrucksForToday(@Param("today") int today);
...
}
```

I have this method that does an join on two tables and returns some data, I have an object that represents this data called `TruckLocation` (that does not exist in the DB). However it wont map automatically (all the attribute names match) I tried using a `@SqlResultSetMapping` and a `Converter` to remap the `ResultSet` back together but the former doesn't operate on a method and the latter requires there to be a [database representation of the resulting object](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) which doesn't seem right for my scenario.

Is there a clean(er) way to make this query?

Comment: At least 2 options come to mind: 1)define @SqlResultSetMapping in XML or 2) provide custom implementation for this method and use a ResultTransformer

Comment: How would you provide custom implementation if it resides in an interface? Will JPA work properly if I implement this interface and write methods?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define an interface with get methods matching the names of the returned attributes. for example

```sql
select x, y, x+y as z from b;
```

the interface would be

```java
interface NonDBEntity{
    getX();
    getY();
    getZ();
}
```

and the call would be

```java
@Query(value = "select x, y, x+y as z from b; ", nativeQuery = true)
List<NonDBEntity> findAllSomething();
```